# Cannot composer dump-autoload : permission denied

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working on a project, and I need to use composer dump-autoload but I can't, I can't composer upload or install too, it fail at the end because of this permission issue

there is my error message :

```
dev@MacBook-Pro intranet % composer dump-autoload         
Generating autoload files
Generating class alias map file
> typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure
sh: /Users/dev/Documents/PhpStorm/intranet/vendor/bin/typo3cms: Permission denied
Script typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure handling the typo3-cms-scripts event returned with error code 126
Script @typo3-cms-scripts was called via post-autoload-dump
dev@MacBook-Pro intranet %
```

and there is a part of my composer.json :

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "EBT\\ExtensionBuilder\\": "public/typo3conf/ext/extension_builder/Classes/",
        }
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
```

I tried a "chmod +- vendor/bin/typo3cms" and a sudo composer dump-autoload but it doesn't solve my issue

Someone know what's the solution please ?

update : solved, I just have to use command in my remote server, and not in local

Comment: That `chmod` command does not look fine.

Comment: The solution for "permission denied" is usually setting the right permissions, that's no longer a programming issue but simply to manage your computer.

Comment: Can you tell your OS and file hosting server like ( linux or Windows)?

Comment: @Pankaj, it says "Macbook Pro" right there.

Comment: I am using Windows and Ubuntu. so i can only suggests some link please have a look this and try to solve your problem. 1)  https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchlp1203/mac  ,  2)  https://www.macinstruct.com/tutorials/how-to-set-file-permissions-on-a-mac/

Comment: pankaj, I tried by I was already in write and read, I added staff and everyone is write and read too for trying, but the error still persist

Comment: solved, I just have to use command in my remote server, and not in local

Answer (score 2):

`chmod 2770 ./vendor/bin/typo3cms`

gives you the correct Permissions to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

This might solve it:

```
chmod 777 -R /Users/dev/Documents/PhpStorm/intranet/
```